# Query Strings with Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I'm trying to setup CodeIgniter (v2.1.4) with Query Strings and having problems with passing variables. The pages work when the controller_trigger and function_trigger are passed:

```
example.org/?c=page&m=index
```

But when I try to pass a variable:

```
example.org/?c=page&m=view&id=1
```

The script throws 'Missing argument' and 'Undefined variable' errors.

In 'application/config/config.php' I've set:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

In 'application/config/routes.php' I have:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "page";
```

And my Controller looks like:

```
<?php

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('page_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Page Title';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('page/page_index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function view($id)
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Id Page Title';

        $data['page_item'] = $this->page_model->get_page($id);

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('page/page_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what I've missed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config.php change:

```
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;    #example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
```

Comment: That seems to be set TRUE already. I'm assuming that's the default as I don't remember changing it.

Comment: NO, that's not default. Follow this structure: `example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function`. See your config file for details. Instead of `public function view($id)` try doing `public function view(){$id = $_GET['id']}`

Comment: That worked. Thanks. BTW I've just checked the config file directly inside the zip for CodeIgniter (v2.1.4) and the setting $config['allow_get_array'] is set TRUE be default

Comment: Happie to help buddy ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this

```
example.org?c=page&m=index
```

**without "/"**

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference.